# Remove only the ticks in plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Is it possible to only remove the ticks in plots?

[image]

Comment: Short answer: yes, it is possible. Useful answer(s): try running `xticks([])` (which is basically a degenerate form of Luis's detailed answer below), `set(gca,'TickLength',[0 0])`, or perhaps `set(gca,'TickDir','out')`, depending on what exactly you want the result to look like: no tick marks or labels in `x` axis - no tick marks in any axis - tick marks still present but not cluttering the plot. Check out https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.axis.axes-properties.html#d123e56384 for some possibilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`xticks`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xticks.html) function (or the statement `set(gca, 'xtick', ...)`) to choose which ones you want to display. Doing so will also affect the tick labels, because each tick has an associated label:

```
plot(1:8)
xticks([1 2 3 5 6 8]) % remove ticks and labels at 4 and 7
```

[image]

If you want to remove all ticks from the axis but keep (some or all) labels, you can set the tick length to `0`, which doesn't affect the labels:

```
plot(1:8)
xticks([1 2 3 5 6 8]) % remove ticks and labels at 4 and 7
set(get(gca, 'XAxis'), 'TickLength', [0 0]) % make all ticks have size 0
```

[image]

Comment: You can even say `xticks off` or similar, right? `xticks()` or something.

Comment: @Adriaan Yes, `xticks([])` will do that (it's a particular case of the first code snippet)